# access H2O dataframe from R

Tags: r, h2o

Newby question in R/H2O, I want to access H2O both from Flow (the web) and from R. I've created a dataframe from R and can see it on H2O. I have created another dataframe in H2O directly, and asking how to get a handle to it in R?

Comment: Have you tried `h2o::h2o.importFile()`?

Comment: Andrew hi, I haven't tried, but from the documentation it should be doing something else. In Flow, I can see two frames. One that I've pushed to H2O from R (using uploadFile), and one that I've created from Flow. But now I want to access that one from R also..

Comment: df <- data.frame(dataframe)

Comment: karen hi, did not work for me, tried as a string, and also without quotes. As string I end up with a dataframe with the string itself, without quotes  object not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a handle to an H2O frame called "xxx":

```
data <- h2o.getFrame("xxx")
```

If you also need that data in your R session (which you don't if you are just going to be using it to train models, make predictions on, etc.) then you follow it with:

```
df <- as.data.frame(data)
```

(Nothing special about the `data` and `df` naming.)